# Surrogate loss function for F-beta score

Tags: loss-function

from the paper, "A Surrogate Loss Function for Optimization of Fβ Score in Binary Classification with Imbalanced Data"
How can I implement the surrogate loss of the f-beta score,  proposed in the formulas (22), to train a deep neural networks for the binary classification problem.

I appreciate any help.

I was unable to understand how to compute the derivative using PyTorch or TensorFlow.